# Running binary on mounted drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, firefox, mount

I am curious to know if something is possible. What I want to do is run the binary of firefox that is installed in an old, half broke linux (solus) laptop that I can't boot into anymore. I want to run it in the state that it was left on a couple years ago so that it will still be logged into the same firefox account to recover some otherwise lost bookmarks.

So, I booted into a fresh live solus usb and mounted the drive and am able to see the firefox binary in //usr/bin, but when I try to run it (or check its version), it runs/reports firefox 89. Which is super confusing because that binary should not be version 89, because that laptop hasnt even been turned on since firefox 89 was released (and solus does not do automatic updates). I am figuring that it is maybe pulling some other libraries or something from the iso image to run firefox. To avoid the obvious question, yes I am running firefox using the full path to the mounted drive's /usr/bin so I was really suprised that this is happening. When I try to run other binaries that are only installed on the drive, I get errors about missing shared libraries. Is it possible to run a binary fully from a mounted drive like this? Is there something obviously wrong I might be doing to get this weird version behavior?

Comment: Where is the profile folder? That's really what you're after, though you might need to use an older compatible Firefox version to access it. Maybe what was current at that time, if you know when that was.

Comment: So, the actual cause for this question is that I did a refresh of my distro on my current laptop and therefore lost all profile data, then tried to log back in to my firefox sync account to reclaim it, only to find out that I didn't know my password. So the goal here was to run firefox from that old hard drive where I would still be logged in, so I could perform a sync to update the bookmarks on that drive to its present day state, then copy that profile data into a new account on my current laptop. So just getting the profile data from that drive would be insufficient since it was very old

Comment: As it turns out, I did finally remember my password, so none of this is necessary now, but I'm leaving it as a future resource

Answer (score 0):

Take an actual look at the binary. So far you've only seen that *something* named "firefox" is there, but not *what* it is. Run `ls -l` on it to verify whether it's a regular file or a link; or `file` to additionally examine its contents. Is it really a binary? More likely it'll be something else: a) a symbolic link to the real binary, or b) a shell script that launches the real binary.

```
$ ls -l /mnt/usr/bin/firefox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 45 Aug 10 21:41 /mnt/usr/bin/firefox*
                       ^^- too small to be a real binary

$ file /mnt/usr/bin/firefox
/mnt/usr/bin/firefox: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

$ cat /mnt/usr/bin/firefox
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/lib/firefox/firefox "$@"
```

Because it executes another program using an absolute path, it will always end up executing the one found in the host OS.

(In this case, the script doesn't do much at all – in fact it could've just been a symlink – so the easiest workaround is to go to the mounted drive's /usr/lib/firefox and run the actual binary found there.)

Comment: You were right, it was just pointing to /<mounted drive>/usr/lib/firefox/firefox. Running that though gives errors about missing shared objects -- couldn't load XPCOM. Presumably it is doing the same thing, where it is looking for these other files with absolute paths and cant find them in the live image root. Is there a way to get firefox to treat the hdd root as root?

Comment: Now, if there are absolute paths all over the place, your main OS settings will also be accessed or maybe even overwritten - that might not be what you wish for. Generally running software "on the side" of the main OS / install like this is a nice way to destroy the order you have in your OS... and; it can be really hard to restore the havoc.